# Adding google map in ionic2 APP using javascript API

Tags: css, typescript, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to create a basic ionic2 app with google maps as per [this tutorial](https://www.joshmorony.com/ionic-2-how-to-use-google-maps-geolocation-video-tutorial/)

In the tutorial, google map is integrated in `home` page and the style elements for the same is kept in `home.scss`

In my app I would like to integrate maps in a different page named `temple`. So i kept style elements in scss of temples page `temples.scss`. But, i don't see the map by doing this and the map shows up fine if i keep the style elements in `home.scss`. I am confused with this behaviour.

Now my question is, to add maps, is it mandatory to keep style elements only in `home.scss` irrespective of the page i add maps to? If not, please point where i am going wrong.

Below is my app code...

**Code from temple.html:**

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <button menuToggle>
            <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
        </button>
        <ion-title>தாங்கல்</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content  class="temple">
  <div #map id="map"></div>
</ion-content>
```

**Code from temple.ts:**

```
import {Component, ViewChild, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';

declare var google;
@Component({
selector: 'temple-page',
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/temples/temples.html'
})
export class TemplesPage {
@ViewChild('map') mapElement: ElementRef;
map: any;
  constructor(private navCtrl: NavController) {}

  ionViewLoaded(){this.loadMap();}

  loadMap(){
    let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(8.117042, 77.491573);
    let mapOptions = {
      center: latLng,
      zoom: 15,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);
  }
}
```

**Code from home.scss:**

```
//This component is linked with map in temples page
//Map component content starts here
.ios, .md
{
temple-page{
          .scroll-content {height: 100%}
          #map {width: 100%;height: 100%;}
         }
}
//Map component content ends here
```

**Screenshot of my app's folder structure**
[image]

Comment: Can you check if the css actual applies to the element? Please note that you cant have two divs with map element. Just one

Comment: Yes, i confirmed it. CSS content available in `home.scss` is somehow linked with div in `temples.html`. If i move the CSS content from `home.scss` to `temples.scss` the map does not show up. I would like to keep all codes of a page in the same directory.

Comment: Does your scss work with selectors? As in temple-page or home-page?

Comment: It is linked to temple-page. I hope i got your question correctly, do you ask if my `temple.scss` is linked/connected with temple-page selector or home-page selector?

Comment: Can i have my app without selector? I mean, currently, if i remove selector then the map will not show up. I would like to know the changes i have to do to remove selector and show map.

Comment: ` <div id="map" style="height:100%;"></div>` I did this. Actually, using selector was screwing up my side menu as well. Now i do not need selector.